# Scrape website with Google Sheets IMPORTXML function

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, scrape

I need to scrape the "Cpn Rate Ann Amt" cell from this website [LINK](https://www.quantumonline.com/search.cfm?tickersymbol=BAC-P&sopt=symbol).

I have tried this:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.quantumonline.com/search.cfm?tickersymbol=BAC-P&sopt=symbol","/html/body/font/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/p[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/font")
```

as suggested by literally every tutorial I saw online, but I just couldn't get it to work. Maybe it just doesn't work since the website has .cfm pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- From `I need to scrape the "Cpn Rate Ann Amt" cell from this website LINK.`, you want to retrieve the value of the header of `Cpn Rate Ann Amt` using IMPORTXML.

In this case, how about the following sample formula and xpath? When I saw the HTML in the URL, I thought that the background color of `<tr bgcolor="FFEFB5">` is only the table, and this might be able to be used as the xpath.

#### Sample formula:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//tr[@bgcolor='FFEFB5']/../tr[2]/td[2]")
```

- The cell "A1" has the URL of `https://www.quantumonline.com/search.cfm?tickersymbol=BAC-P&sopt=symbol`.

#### Result:

[image]

#### Note:

- When you want to the value of `Cpn Rate Ann Amt`, you can also use the following formula.

  ```
    =IMPORTXML(A1,"//tr[@bgcolor='FFEFB5']/th[2]")
  ```
- In this sample formula and xpath are for the URL of `https://www.quantumonline.com/search.cfm?tickersymbol=BAC-P&sopt=symbol`. So when the URL is changed, the xpath might not work. So please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)

Comment: Thank you. You are just awesome. Not only did you give me the answer to my question, but you explained the whole process to me and included screenshots. You are awesome and you are what this community should be all about - helping people solve their problem through teaching them the process, so that we can further spread our knowledge should someone else also have a similar problem.

Comment: @Nataliikaa PetroOwwa Thank you for replying. I'm honored for it. And, I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.